# How to use Kubernetes fieldSelector to query ownerReferences

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, client-go

Does Kubernetes GET API actually support [`fieldSelector` parameter](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/) to query values of array fields?

For example, I have a Pod like:

```
apiGroup: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: grpc-ping-r7f8r-deployment-54d688d777
    uid: 262bab1a-1c79-11ea-8e23-42010a800016
```

Can I do something like:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector 'metadata.ownerReferences.uid=262bab1a-1c79-11ea-8e23-42010a800016'
```

This command fails (*`field label not supported: metadata.ownerReferences.uid`*). I suspect the reason is that `ownerReferences` is an array field itself. I've also tried, but didn't work:

- `metadata.ownerReferences[*].uid=`
- `metadata.ownerReferences[].uid=`

I might try client-go SDK for Kubernetes API, but I suspect it won't work for the same reason.

Is there a server-side way to query by this? Thanks much.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `--field-selector` only works with some limited fields.

Which contains:

```
"metadata.name",
"metadata.namespace",
"spec.nodeName",
"spec.restartPolicy",
"spec.schedulerName",
"spec.serviceAccountName",
"status.phase",
"status.podIP",
"status.podIPs",
"status.nominatedNodeName"
```

- [Reference](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9d577d8a29893062dfbd669997396dbd01ab0e47/pkg/apis/core/v1/conversion.go#L33)

But you can perform the task by using `jq`. Here is a command that I used for listing all ready nodes. It demonstrates the use of array fields that you're looking for.

```bash
$ kubectl get nodes -o json | jq -r '.items[] | select(.status.conditions[] | select(.type=="Ready" and .status=="True")) | .metadata.name '

master-0
node-1
node-3
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to find which fields are searchable through field selector. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/ the docs don't have it. It seems like what I'm trying to do is not possible.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google always welcome, though I knew you didn't need this one :P but might help others.

Comment: The big difference: field selectors work on the server side. Tools like jq/yq/jsonpath or client go Indexing work on the client side. The client side has the drawback that all objects need to get transferred over the wire. Sometimes this not noticeable, sometimes it is.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you really want to do is a filter rather than a query.  By using [JSONPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) you can filter out content using `?()`.

For example the following would work:

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(.metadata.ownerReferences.uid=262bab1a-1c79-11ea-8e23-42010a800016)]}{.metadata.name}{end}'
```