# Filtering items are stored in Kubernetes shared informer cache

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I have a Kubernetes controller written using client-go [informers](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/informers) package. It maintains a watch on all Pods in the cluster, there are about 15k of these objects, and their YAML representation takes around 600 MB to print (I assume their in-memory representation is not that different.)

As a result, this (otherwise really small) controller watching Pods ends up with a huge memory footprint (north of 1 GiB). Even methods that you'd think offer a way of filtering, such as the one named like [`NewFilteredSharedInformerFactory`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/informers#NewFilteredSharedInformerFactory) doesn't really give you a way to specify a predicate function that chooses which objects are stored in the in-memory `cache`.

Instead, that method in client-go offers a [`TweakListOptionsFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.24.2/informers/internalinterfaces#TweakListOptionsFunc). It helps you control `ListOptions` but my predicate unfortunately cannot be satisfied with a `labelSelector` or `fieldSelector`. I need to drop the objects when they arrive to the controller through a predicate function.

> Note: the predicate I have is something like *"Pods that have an ownerReference by a DaemonSet"* (which is [not possible with `fieldSelectors`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442065/how-to-use-kubernetes-fieldselector-to-query-ownerreferences) –also another question of mine) and there's no `labelSelector` that can work in my scenario.

How would I go about configuring an informer on Pods that only have DaemonSet owner references to reduce the memory footprint of my controller?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve through informers on `Pod` that are owned by DS only? Maybe that will help provide alternatives.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to watch Pods owned only by various daemonsets.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea, you can get a list of all the `DaemonSets` in your cluster. Read the `spec.selector.matchLabels` field to retrieve the label that the `DaemonSet` pods are bound to have. Use those labels as part of your `TweakListOptionsFunc` with a logic like:

```
Pods with label1 OR label2 OR label3 ...
```

I know it's a bit of toil, but seems to be a working approach. I believe there isn't a way to specify fields in `client-go`.

Comment: I actually do know the DaemonSets I am interested in ahead of time and could do what you said. However (1) they're across namespaces, and I don't want to query all namespaces since the memory footprint is quite high (2) `ListOptions` doesn't let you specify complex expressions like that (e.g. `matchExpressions`). The API Machinery allows only `=`,`!=` on `labelSelector`/`fieldSelector` on `List` APIs, sadly.

Comment: You don't have to query all elements of a namespace, just retrieve DaemonSet manifests. It should be a much smaller footprint, no?

Comment: No, I actually need to watch Pods that have DaemonSets as their owners. The purpose of my controller is to watch if certain DaemonSet Pods on a `Node` are running and taint the `Node` based on that.

Comment: Ah I see, and I believe you are not using any node selectors to match DS pods to nodes :(

Answer (score 2):

It appears that today if you use [SharedInformers](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/informers#SharedInformerFactory), there's no way to filters which objects to keep in the shared cache and which ones to discard.

I have found an [interesting code snippet](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/734389481ab1a47422f07e80ef93b4359cadbaed/pkg/sharding/listwatch.go) in kube-state-metrics project that opts into the lower-layer of abstraction of initiating `Watch` calls directly (which would normally be considered as an anti-pattern) and using [`watch.Filter`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.25.0/pkg/watch#Filter), it decides whether to return an object from a Watch() call (to a cache/reflector or not).

That said, many controller authors might choose to not go down this path as it requires you to specify your own cache/reflector/indexer around the Watch() call. Furthermore, projects like `controller-runtime` don't even let you get access to this low-level machinery, as far as I know.

---

Another aspect of reducing controllers' memory footprint can be done through field/data erasure on structs (instead of discarding objects altogether). This is possible in newer versions of `client-go` through [`cache.TransformFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.24.2/tools/cache#TransformFunc), which can let you delete fields of irrelevant objects (though, these objects would still consume some memory). This one is more of a band-aid that can make your situation better.

---

In my case, I mostly needed to watch for DaemonSet Pods in certain namespaces, so I refactored the code from using 1 informer (watching all namespaces) to N namespace-scoped informers running concurrently.