# How to provide Owner Reference to the `ListOptions` of KubeBuilder's List method?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubebuilder

I want to list the pods that are owned by the resource `X` from the Kubernetes cluster using Kubuilder's  `List(ctx context.Context, list ObjectList, opts ...ListOption)` method.  `ListOptions` contains options for limiting or filtering results. Here is the the structure of the `ListOptions`

```golang
type ListOptions struct {
    // LabelSelector filters results by label. Use labels.Parse() to
    // set from raw string form.
    LabelSelector labels.Selector
    // FieldSelector filters results by a particular field.  In order
    // to use this with cache-based implementations, restrict usage to
    // a single field-value pair that's been added to the indexers.
    FieldSelector fields.Selector

    // Namespace represents the namespace to list for, or empty for
    // non-namespaced objects, or to list across all namespaces.
    Namespace string

    // Limit specifies the maximum number of results to return from the server. The server may
    // not support this field on all resource types, but if it does and more results remain it
    // will set the continue field on the returned list object. This field is not supported if watch
    // is true in the Raw ListOptions.
    Limit int64
    // Continue is a token returned by the server that lets a client retrieve chunks of results
    // from the server by specifying limit. The server may reject requests for continuation tokens
    // it does not recognize and will return a 410 error if the token can no longer be used because
    // it has expired. This field is not supported if watch is true in the Raw ListOptions.
    Continue string

    // Raw represents raw ListOptions, as passed to the API server.  Note
    // that these may not be respected by all implementations of interface,
    // and the LabelSelector, FieldSelector, Limit and Continue fields are ignored.
    Raw *metav1.ListOptions
}
```

Now, How can I provide the owner information to this `ListOptions` so the `List` method will only list the pods that are owned by `X`?

Here is an example from the KubeBuilder book that shows how to filter results by a particular field,

```golang
  listOps := &client.ListOptions{
        FieldSelector: fields.OneTermEqualSelector(configMapField, configMap.GetName()),
        Namespace:     configMap.GetNamespace(),
  }
  err := r.List(context.TODO(), attachedConfigDeployments, listOps)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not possible to use field selector for every field of a resource. In your case for example, you can only use [these fields](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9d577d8a29893062dfbd669997396dbd01ab0e47/pkg/apis/core/v1/conversion.go#L33) as field selector. It's also stated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59443446/11764782).

Alternatively, you can put labels to pods that is owned by a custom resource and use label selectors. Or you can get all pods and apply programmatic filter to get necessary pods. (I recommend the first approach since `metadata.ownerReferences` is an array and the cost is O(n^2))

Comment: You can use field selectors for any field IF you add an index to that field.

You would do something like `mgr.GetFieldIndexer().IndexField(...)` to build/maintain the index.